# Django: instance one field from form

Tags: django, forms, view, field, instance

I have a form (a regular one, not a ModelForm), which I need one of its fields to load initialized.

I would need to do something like this:

views.py

```
def my_view(request):
    my_var = MyClass.objects.get(my_filter=my_value).a_var
    form = MyForm(my_form_field = my_var)
```

I would need to initialize the value of one of the fields of `MapeoForm`. I only know how to populate a ModelForm with a class object instance so far.

Take into account that this form has more than one field, but I need to load the form with only this field populated and the rest by default (blank).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [`initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) argument.

```
form = MyForm(initial={'my_form_field': my_var})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [initial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) to load dynamic value to django form.

```
In [6]: from django import forms
   ...: class SampleForm(forms.Form):
   ...:     name = forms.CharField()
   ...:     
   ...: f = SampleForm(initial={'name': 'this is name'})
   ...: print(f)
   ...: 
   ...: 
<tr><th><label for="id_name">Name:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="name" value="this is name" required id="id_name" /></td></tr>

In [7]:
```

You can also pass default initial value to field itself,

```
In [7]: from django import forms
   ...: class SampleForm(forms.Form):
   ...:     name = forms.CharField(initial='this is default name')
   ...:     
   ...: f = SampleForm()
   ...: print(f)
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: 
<tr><th><label for="id_name">Name:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="name" value="this is default name" required id="id_name" /></td></tr>

In [8]:
```